# How to query in multi-tenant applications?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, model, schema

I'm about to develop a [multi-tenant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy) application, but I have some doubts about how to query and how to build a schema to work properly since users can create new users.

I mean. Users will have a `parent_id` attribute to know who are their creator, but Users should be able to se Entities created by their children and their children's children etc...

For example, User (1) creates User (2) who creates User (3), each Product will have an `user_id` attribute to specify the owner/creator, but for the User (2) his Product list should list products with `user_id` equals to 2 AND 3. For User (1) he should be able to see Products owned by 1, 2 AND 3. User (3) will see only his own since he does not have child users.

Is this the best way to work? How to query a data model like that?

Comment: I would look at Postgres 9.5 (out any day) which has Row Security and might help in this situation

Answer (score 0):

You would want to create an authorization table. When User 1 creates a new entity, a record is created with User ID and Entity/Tenant ID. When User 3, created by User 1, creates a new entity - a new record should be created with User ID 1 and Tenant ID and User ID 3 and Tenant ID.

Your products table will have a tenant ID for each product. If Product X is tenant ID 3 - then User 1 and User 3 which have access to tenant ID 3 should be able to see it.

This could be done by loading all products which belong to tenants which the user is authorized to view.

Answer (score 0):

I reach the following solution: Using a path for each user then query by that path.

Each `User` has a `path` column, the value is his parent User path + his own ID.

```
    #     users    #  #   entities   #
    # id #   path  #  # id # user_id #
    |  1 |     .1. |  |  1 |    1    |
    |  2 |   .1.2. |  |  2 |    2    |
    |  3 |   .1.3. |  |  3 |    3    |
    |  4 | .1.2.4. |  |  4 |    4    |
    |  5 |     .5. |  |  5 |    5    |
    |  6 |   .5.6. |  |  6 |    6    |
```

`SELECT * FROM entities e LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = e.user_id
WHERE path LIKE "%.1.%"`

This fetches 1, 2, 3 and 4. E1 is from U1, E2 and E3 are from U1 children and E4 is from U2 who is U1's child.

- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f32ba9/2

I'll still be listening for better solutions.